# Not able to connect postgresql with django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

I've created a database named `testdb1` in `postgresql` and I am trying to connect it with my `django` app. But when I run `python manage.py syncdb` I get the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "testdb1" does not exist`. The database does exist as it is confirmed by the following:

```
archit@archit-Inspiron-5520:~/Documents/DjangoLabs/gswd$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.1.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \connect testdb1
You are now connected to database "testdb1" as user "postgres".
testdb1=# \d
          List of relations
 Schema |  Name   | Type  |  Owner   
--------+---------+-------+----------
 public | company | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

In `settings.py` I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'testdb1',                      
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

In `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
local   all         postgres                          md5
```

**EDIT:**

`\du` command gives:

```
testdb1=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 archit    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same error when deploying one of the projects. I don't remember but solution was very easy. E.g. try to add PORT in your settings.py or other stuff like this.

Comment: I had a similar issue but mine was that I would create the database on my local machine in pgAdmin but in the command line on the server it automatically lowercases everything.  In my settings file it had uppercase and so Django didn't recognize the database.  Doesn't seem to be the issue here, but others might run into it.

Answer (score 1):

Drop database and re create database.

In settings.py write 'PORT'='5432' or '5433' as this is the common port in all postgresql.

Then do syncdb or migrate.

Comment: Have you installed psycopg2?

Comment: Yes I have it installed.

Answer (score -2):

Since your table was created without the tools of Django. You will need to write down an Model class and set some Metal information about the "custom" name format of your table: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#table-names

If you can, i recommend you to drop this table and use the Django ORM to build up your database. It's more fast and simple than write everything in SQL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models

Comment: Even after dropping the table it gives the same error.

Comment: You're setting the **port** to **blank string** try put the default port or just remove it from the dict. And follow the tutorial! You have to build the database with syncdb or migrate (depends on the version of django)

Comment: @ArchitVerma you have to `recreate` the db after dropping then perform syncdb.

Comment: @rajasimon he doesn't need to drop at all. He can use their db/tables with building up from ORM.

Comment: @rajasimon I agree. But the table already being there shouldn't be the problem.